# Java Program to Enter a sentence and print the longest word

Tags: java

This a program to enter a sentence and print the longest word using substring()
Here, I have used the 1st loop to extract each word from the sentence and find the length of the longest word.
In the 2nd Loop, its purpose is it to extract and print the word that matches the length which was found out in the 1st loop and stored in the "longestLength" variable.

I am getting an error when i compile the following code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s, st;
        int longestLength = 0;
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Sentence");
        s = sc.nextLine();
        s = s.trim();
        s = s+" ";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                i2 = i;
                st = s.substring(i1, i2);
                if (st.length() > longestLength)
                    longestLength = st.length();
                i1 = i;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                i2 = i;
                st = s.substring(i1, i2);
                if (st.length() == longestLength) {
                    System.out.println("Longest Word : " + st);
                    break;
                }
                i1=i;
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If you get an error, include the actual error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you **don't need to use for loops** for just finding the longest word.

Just remove the for loops and add the following lines below that.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Sentence");
    s = sc.nextLine();
    s = s.trim();
    s = s+" ";

    String longest = Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).orElse(null);

    System.out.println(longest);
```

YOUR FINAL CODE WILL BE:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;
        int longestLength = 0;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Sentence");
        s = sc.nextLine();
        s = s.trim();
        
        String longest = Arrays.stream(s.split(" ")).max(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).orElse(null);
    
        System.out.println(longest);
    }
}
```

It will print the longest word. Hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate easy method to split sentence using delimter using String.spilt(delimiter) funciton.
Below code is an working example for your task

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s, st;
        int longestLength = 0;
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Sentence");
        s = sc.nextLine();

        String maxString = "";
        for(String string : s.split(" ")){
            maxString = maxString.length() > string.length() ? maxString : string;
        }

        System.out.println("The max lengthed string is : "+maxString);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to i1 has not be resetted to 0 hence the old loop value if i1 is there hence the issue

The solution is given below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s, st;
        int longestLength = 0;
        int i1 = 0;
        int i2;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Sentence");
        s = sc.nextLine();
        s = s.trim();
        s = s+" ";

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                i2 = i;
                st = s.substring(i1, i2);
                if (st.length() > longestLength)
                    longestLength = st.length();
                i1 = i;
            }
        }

        i1=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
                i2 = i;
                st = s.substring(i1, i2);
                if (st.length() == longestLength) {
                    System.out.println("Longest Word : " + st);
                    break;
                }
                i1=i;
            }


        }

    }
```